# Change layout direction of a Composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to set a direction of a specific composable to be **RTL**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ViewToBeChanged() {
  Row {
     Image()
     Column {
        Text("Title")
        Text("Subtitle")
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible?

Jetpack compose [**Layout documentation**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layout#layout-direction) mentions `LocalLayoutDirection`

> Change the layout direction of a composable by changing the `LocalLayoutDirection` compositionLocal.

But I have no idea how to use it in a composable to take effect.

Comment: If you don't want to switch to RTL layouts but just want to draw the layout in a different way then top-to-bottom (like `Column`)  or start-to-end (like `Row`) then the flexibility of `ConstraintLayout` might be what you're looking for.
There is a compose implementation: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/constraintlayout

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use the [**`CompositionLocalProvider`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/CompositionLocal) to  provide a custom [**`LocalLayoutDirection`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#locallayoutdirection).

Something like:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl ) {
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Text("Title")
        Text("Subtitle")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Since I did not have your image, I tweaked your composable to:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ViewToBeChanged() {
  Row {
    Text("Foo", modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp))

    Column {
      Text("Title")
      Text("Subtitle")
    }
  }
}
```

That gives us:

[image: ViewToBeChanged() rendering]

One way to switch to RTL is to use `CompositionLocalProvider` and `LocalLayoutDirection`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun RtlView() {
  CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
    Row {
      Text("Foo", modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp))

      Column {
        Text("Title")
        Text("Subtitle")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here, we are saying that we are overriding the `CompositionLocal` for layout direction for the contents of the trailing lambda supplied to `CompositionLocalProvider()`. This gives us:

[image: RtlView() rendering]

This changes the layout direction used by this branch of the composable tree, for the composables itself. English is still a LTR language, so the text is unaffected.

Answer (score 7):

Using CompositionLocalProvider to change orientation has the potential risk of causing all child layouts to change orientation, which may not be what we expect. And using LazyColumn or LazyRow can invert the layout but the functionality of the child layouts will be limited and there are some strange restrictions, so here is my solution

```
@Composable
fun ReversibleRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    horizontalArrangement: Arrangement.Horizontal = Arrangement.Start,
    verticalAlignment: Alignment.Vertical = Alignment.Top,
    reverseLayout: Boolean = false,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val originDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current
    val direction = when {
        reverseLayout -> when (originDirection) {
            LayoutDirection.Rtl -> LayoutDirection.Ltr
            else -> LayoutDirection.Rtl
        }
        else -> originDirection
    }
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides direction) {
        Row(modifier, horizontalArrangement, verticalAlignment) {
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides originDirection) {
                content()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use ReversibleRow to replace Row. same for Column

Answer (score 5):

As a generalisation of the other answers, if this is needed in different Composables we can define the following

```kotlin
@Composable
fun RightToLeftLayout(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
        content()
    }
}
```

then simply use

```kotlin
RightToLeftLayout {
    ViewToBeChanged()
}
```

or

```kotlin
RightToLeftLayout {
    Row {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For a `Row` specifically, you can influence the RTL / LTR behavior using the `horizontalArrangement` parameter. The default is `Arrangement.Start` which takes into account layout direction. Using one of [`Arrangement.Absolute`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement.Absolute) allows you to give an arrangement that ignores layout direction.

In your example:

```
@Composable
fun ViewToBeChanged() {
  Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Right) {
     Image()
     Column {
        Text("Title")
        Text("Subtitle")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. As mentioned in other comments, using `CompositionLocalProvider` has the risk of modifying all of the elements in the subtree.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to change all activity direction, you can wrap your surface component by:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl){
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                   
                   
                }

            }
```