# Last composables in Row() get squeezed (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a custom search bar; in which I am using `Row()` composable as a container for all the other elements. Here the last `FloatingActionButton` gets squeezed but I want the `TextField` to be flexible so that it gets shortened to accommodate the remaining elements.

[image: Last element squeezed in Row]

I already know some workarounds to this but I want a better solution. See below for the known workarounds and their drawbacks.

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 410)
@Composable
fun MyComposable() {
    Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        TextField(value = "Search", onValueChange = {})
        FloatingActionButton(onClick = {}) {Icon(Icons.Filled.SkipNext, contentDescription = null)}
        FloatingActionButton(onClick = {}) {Icon(Icons.Filled.Close, contentDescription = null)}
        FloatingActionButton(onClick = {}) {Icon(Icons.Filled.Home, contentDescription = null)}
    }
}
```

##### Known workarounds:

1. Using `ConstraintLayout` (Drawback: Complicated. Seems like overkill in many situations.)
2. [Using `CompositionLocalProvider`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66835210/jetpack-compose-change-layout-direction-of-a-composable) to  provide a RTL `LocalLayoutDirection`. (Drawback: Seems hacky. All the layouts of child components become RTL. For example textfield icons and text placement.)
3. Specifying fixed width (or weights) to the last element. (Drawback: This makes the second last element to squeeze and forces me to hardcode width which cannot be done on some elements like `Button` as its width is determined by localized text in it.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can apply the `weight(1f)` to the `TextField`:

```
Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            value = "Search", onValueChange = {})

        FloatingActionButton(onClick = {}) {Icon(Icons.Filled.SkipNext, contentDescription = null)}
        FloatingActionButton(onClick = {}) {Icon(Icons.Filled.Close, contentDescription = null)}
        FloatingActionButton(onClick = {}) {Icon(Icons.Filled.Home, contentDescription = null)}
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: @CarterHudson because it tells the search bar to take 100% of the width after the other elements' widths have been taken into account. Without the weight, each of the components have a given width which is together more than the available space, so something has to be reduced. Compose reduces the last item, which produces OP's problem.